# Use of modifier or type 'unsigned' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012 Directive 4.6, advisory]

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

I am using MACRO `#define` for different data types as below.

```
#define CCP_BYTE    unsigned char
#define CCP_WORD    unsigned short
#define CCP_DWORD   unsigned long
```

Observed below warning at many statements (146 in number) wherever I am using these `MACROs`.

> Use of modifier or type 'unsigned' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012
>   Directive 4.6, advisory]
>
> Use of modifier or type 'short' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012
>   Directive 4.6, advisory]
>
> Use of modifier or type 'long' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012
>   Directive 4.6, advisory]

Observed warning at all the instance wherever I am typecasting test condition in if statement as below.

> Use of modifier or type '_Bool' outside of a typedef [MISRA 2012
>   Directive 4.6, advisory]

```
if( !(bool) ChkStatus)
{
  /* execute if satisfy */    
}
```

I referred [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607456/does-misra-c-2012-say-not-to-use-bool/30614236#30614236) which talks about this query for bool type.  However, Is there any way other than disabling this rule to get rid of these warnings.

Comment: Why not typedef?

Comment: For bool, it is working with typedef bool CCP_BOOL; Checking for others.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to have your own "garage standard" types instead of `stdint.h`? Obfuscation? Code golf?

Comment: Btw why do you tag this QA-C if you are using Lint? Which tool are you actually using?

Comment: @Lundin corrected, removed tag QA-C.

Comment: I've edited your older posts and removed the tag there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule 4.6 says that you should be using types for size and signedness, such as the `stdint.h` types, instead of default `unsigned int` etc.

Meaning that you are allowed to create your own custom `typedef` if you are stuck with C90. Otherwise you should use `stdint.h`. This in turn means that your tool will only allow `unsigned int` etc together with a `typedef`, not together with a `#define` etc.

As noted, the remark about `bool` is a false positive. Apparently it is a tool bug in Lint, which has been confirmed by the tool vendor as per comments in the linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30614236/584518).

MISRA-C requires one boolean type to be used, but doesn't name it. Likely you have to configure the static analyser so that it knows what the bool type used is called. Using `_Bool`, `bool` or even a custom type is fine as far as MISRA is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

> However, Is there any way other than disabling this rule to get rid of these warnings.

That is definitely the wrong thing to do. You should solve the problems, not hide the messages.

---

Using a `#define` instead of a `typedef` is bad practice. One of the main advantages of using `typedef` is that type can be checked properly during compile time.

Imagine the following:

```
#define LENGTH int
#define MASS int
```

and

```
typedef int tLength
typedef int tMass
```

Now it is obvious that two variables of types tLength and tMass will have different types. But two variables defined as LENGTH and MASS will have the same type (`int`).

Typecasting (e.g.) from tLength to tMass is likely to raise at least a warning, as lengths and masses are not compatible, but converting from LENGTH to MASS will go undetected.

---

There was (I do not have access to the documents now) and maybe there still is a MISRA rule saying that relying on any code (including the standard library) provided along with the compiler is forbidden.

This means that you have to define / write everything yourself.

---

Note

Modern compilers add more and more static analysis capabilities. However:

- these capabilities are many times quite limited;
- these capabilities tend to be disabled by default.

Even if all static analysis is enabled, the compiler itself **might** not detect some things (e.g. the difference between tLength and tMass above).

However, (especially that we are in the context of `pc-lint`), static analysis tools look **exactly** after those kinds of stuff, and generate the according messages.

Bottom line: to have "the safest" program you need to use best coding practices, in order to aid the static analysis tools to do their best job. (be aware: only best practices and static analysis are no guarantee for a perfect program = hence the quotation marks)

Comment: `tLength` and `tMass` *are the same type*. Type aliases are shallow, nothing is stopping you from adding "mass" to "length" here. I'm not saying one should use macros, but from a pure C perspective, this doesn't appear to be a good reason.

Comment: Nothing is perfect, I agree. But `typedef`s are potentially safer, in the long run, than `#define`s. Even if adding is allowed, some warning will be generated, especially by a static analysis tool (unless the warnings are disabled). While LENGTH and MASS are only seen by the pre-processor (`int` being passed to the compiler in both cases), tLength and tMass are seen by the compiler.

Comment: Compilers warning about aliases is unlikely. Never encountered one anyway. Static analysis tools are a different beast. You may want to make the distinction clearer in your answer.

Comment: The rationale for the rule in question is explicitly that fixed size/sign types like `stdint.h` should be used. The define vs typedef thing is just a side-effect of that rule.